# How to count left joined rows?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
articles:
id
title
text
timestamp

articles_views:
id
article_id
timestamp
```

I need sql query which would return list of all articles ordered by articles_views count for that article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.id
    , a.Title
    , COUNT(v.id)
FROM
    articles a
LEFT JOIN
    article_views v
ON a.id = v.article_id
GROUP BY
    a.id, a.title
ORDER BY
    COUNT(v.id) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem-

```
SELECT articles.*, 
(select count(*) from `articles_views` C where P.id = C.article_id ) as CNT 
FROM articles P inner join articles_views C 
  ON P.id = C.article_id group by P.id
order by cnt desc
```